# Como eu posso usar dois bancos diferentes para uma loja Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Eu uso o sistema multi-store do Magento e tenho duas lojas. Uma eu instalei o tema com sucesso, a outra eu apenas importei os arquivos Skin, App, Media etc, mas não sei como proceder para importar o banco de dados referente a este segundo tema.

O sistema multi-store já está funcionamento corretamente, mas o layout logicamente não funciona apenas com a importação dos arquivos indicados.

Answer (score 1):

Dois bancos não sera possível.

Você não irá conseguir importar a base demo para a segunda loja, tera de montar sozinho mesmo.

Já passei por isto.